How to make a work item field read-only using an Azure DevOps extension?
I'm developing an extension for Azure DevOps and I need to make specific work item fields read-only(In UI) based on certain conditions.
How can I make a specific field read-only using the Azure DevOps extension framework? Is there a specific API or method that allows setting a work item field to read-only?
I have explored the WorkItemFormService but did not find any methods that allow setting a field to read-only.
I have also checked the Azure DevOps documentation but did not find relevant information or examples related to making a field read-only through an extension.

Instead of using a custom extension, Azure DevOps has the built-in feature "work item rules" that can mark a field read-only under certain conditions. For more details, see the following docs: - Add a custom rule  - Apply a field rule

Hi @Bright Ran, Is it possible ? if we are following XML process.

Sure, you can configure work item rules in XML process. Actually, the docs "Rules and rule evaluation" has stated this.  @SubrahmanyaBhat

There is no available interface (API/CLI) to conditionally mark fields as read-only in work items.
The API "Fields - Update" can mark a field as read-only, but it will cause the field to be read-only in all work items which are using the field, not certain work items.
To conditionally mark fields as read-only in work items, you can use the Azure DevOps built-in feature "Custom rules to work item types". This feature allow to set a rule to mark a specified field as read-only when the specified conditions are met.

Related documentations:

Add a rule to a work item type
Rules and rule evaluation


